# Laravel 5: How to do a join query on a pivot table using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables in my Laravel application namely **customers** and **stores**. Customers can belong to many stores and stores can have many customers. There's a pivot table between them to store that relation.

Question is, how do I extract the list of customers for a given store using Eloquent? Is it possible? I am currently able to extract that using Laravel's **Query Builder**. Here is my code:

```
| customers | stores      | customer_store |
-------------------------------------------
| id        | id          | customer_id    |
| name      | name        | store_id       |
| created_at| created_at  | created_at     |
| updated_at| updated_at  | updated_at     |
```

**Customer Model:**

```
public function stores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class)
            ->withPivot('customer_store', 'store_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Store Model:**

```
public function customers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class)
            ->withPivot('customer_store', 'customer_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**DB Query (using Query Builder):**

```
$customer = DB::select(SELECT customers.id, customers.name, customers.phone, customers.email, customers.location FROM customers LEFT JOIN customer_store on customers.id = customer_store.customer_id WHERE customer_store.store_id = $storeID);
```

Comment: setting things straight [`DB:select`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_select) is not a [`Query Builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_select). If you expect to get `Store`'s customers, you could `$current_store->customers()` and this will fetch all customers belong to the store given that `$current_store` is a model instance - not a collection. If you wish to retrieve several store and fetch their related customers, you could use @kapil.dev answer.

Comment: On a side note, your `->withPivot()` actuall wrong, [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), and you can define relationship key on the relationship itself, ie. [`->belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'customer_store', 'store_id', 'customer_id')`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsToMany)

Comment: @Bagus Tesa ...You maked My day it worked for me  belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'customer_store', 'store_id', 'customer_id')  .......................Thanks..!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public function result(Request $request) {

    $storeId = $request->get('storeId');

    $customers = Customer::whereHas('stores', function($query) use($storeId) {
        $query->where('stores.id', $storeId);
    })->get();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try executing this...

```
$result = Customer::with('stores')->get();
```

Hope this helps.

To know more about Eloquent Relationship refer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I am getting this error after I implemented your code:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_store.customer_store' in 'field list' (SQL: select `stores`.*, `customer_store`.`customer_id` as `pivot_customer_id`, `customer_store`.`store_id` as `pivot_store_id`, `customer_store`.`customer_store` as `pivot_customer_store`, `customer_store`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `customer_store`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `stores` inner join `customer_store` on `stores`.`id` = `customer_store`.`store_id` where `customer_store`.`customer_id` in (1, 2, 3))

Comment: obviously, look on my comment, on your post. however, `->with()` assumes you're loading a collection of `Customers`

Comment: exactly!! @captainblack you should refer BagusTesa's comment, he explained it well.

Comment: @kapil.dev where do you pass the 'store_id'.

Comment: @Anish688 it should be mapped in pivot table  and it will give the mapped store that belongs to that customer.... please read the doc if concept is still unclear..

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

Here `Customers` is your model and `$storeID` is your store id. `$storeID` is outside of the scope of your callback. So you must use the use statement to pass them.

```
Customers::leftJoin('customer_store', function($join) use($storeID){
  $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'customer_store.customer_id')
  ->where('customer_store.store_id','=', $storeID);
})
->whereNotNull('customer_store.store_id')//Not Null Filter
->get();
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: isn't it a bit overly complicated? op wished for it in as eloquent as possible *how do I extract the list of customers for a given store using Eloquent?* perhaps elaborating why did you give this answer, will be the best.

Comment: Hey @AddWeb, your code kinda works, but it also returns all the customers (customers not belonging to that store).

Comment: Yes, based on OP's **DB Query (using Query Builder)** point. I try to given best solution using advance join.

Comment: @captainblack Ok, will provide solution. JAM..!

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd join will work, but whats the use of Eloquent Relationship when we are using joins?

Comment: @captainblack I think there is no prob. I already placed `where('customer_store.store_id','=', $storeID)` for that

Comment: This is the extra customer that is returned with your code:
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "User 3",
    "phone": "102",
    "email": "u3@x.com",
    "location": "WA",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "customer_id": null,
    "store_id": null
  }

Comment: @captainblack: I update my answer with *Not Null Filter*. Check it!

Comment: This one works, however, I feel the solution should be as easy to read as Eloquent queries do.